# Using Bitwise operators on flags

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

I have four flags

```
Current = 0x1  
Past = 0x2  
Future = 0x4  
All = 0x7
```

Say I receive the two flags Past and Future (`setFlags(PAST | FUTURE)`). How can I tell if `Past` is in it? Likewise how can I tell that `Current` is not in it? That way I don't have to test for every possible combination.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you want all bits in the test mask to match:

```
if((value & mask) == mask) {...}
```

If you want any single bit in the test mask to match:

```
if((value & mask) != 0) {...}
```

The difference is most apparent when you are testing a value for multiple things.

To test for exclusion:

```
if ((value & mask) == 0) { }
```

Answer (score 35):

First of all - use enums with FlagAttribute. That's what it's for.

```
[Flags]
public enum Time
{
    None = 0
    Current = 1,
    Past = 2,
    Future = 4
    All = 7
}
```

Testing then is done like this:

```
if ( (x & Time.Past) != 0 )
```

Or this:

```
if ( (x & Time.Past) == Time.Past )
```

The latter will work better if "Past" was a combination of flags and you wanted to test them all.

Setting is like this:

```
x |= Time.Past;
```

Unsetting is like this:

```
x &= ~Time.Past;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I think 1 is not appropriate to be used as flag value? As any flag value (& Operator) with 1, result is still 1.

Comment: @Roylee - not, that's a perfectly normal flag value. It corresponds to exactly one bit. And think about it - for example 4 & 1 = 0.

Comment: Icic. got it :) Then you got to make sure the rest of the flag value sets are *power of 2*, right?

Comment: @Roylee - Exactly! :) Note that "None" and "All" are a bit different - they're not flags themselves, but rather combinations of flags. I could also make `PastOrPresent=3` because `1 & 2 = 3`. It only makes sense to add these for combinations that are often used together. It saves typing and avoids mistakes.

Comment: @Roylee - Aww, hell. I made a typo. It's supposed to be `1 | 2 = 3`. :)

Answer (score 12):

You may also want to add an **extension method** like this

```
  enum states {
     Current = 0x1,
     Past = 0x2,
     Future = 0x4,
     All = 0x7
  };

  static bool Is(this states current, states value) {
     return (current & value) == value;
  }
```

then you can do:

```
 if(state.Is(states.Past)) {
    // Past
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use .NET 4 or later I prefer to do this, cleaner imao:

```
[Flags]
public enum Time
{
    None = 0
    Current = 1,
    Past = 2,
    Future = 4
}

myProp = Time.Past | Time.Future;

if (myProp.HasFlag(Time.Past))
{
    // Past is set...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

An addendum to Marc Gravell and Vilx-'s answer:

Your flagged enum shouldn't specify the amount for "All", it should just include your existing values. This goes for any calculated values.

```
[Flags]
public enum Time
{
    None = 0,
    Current = 1,
    Past = 2,
    Future = 4,
    All = Current | Past | Future
}
```

Note that Vilx- removed the use of Hexadecimal for values. This is important because once you're past 0x8, your values will have to comply with Hex. You should just stay in decimal.

**EDIT:**
I also want to add that you can use bit shifting rather than hex/decimal.

This looks like:

```
[Flags]
public enum Time
{
    None = 0,
    Current = 1,
    Past = 1 << 1, // 2, 10 binary
    Future = 1 << 2, // 4, 100 binary
 // Example = 1 << 3, // 8, 1000 binary
 // Example = 1 << 4, // 16, 10000 binary
    All = Current | Past | Future
}
```

Comment: Could you use something like `Past = 1 << Current, Future = 1 << Past` instead of the hardcoded decimal values?

Comment: @Narshe You could if that's what you prefer. Technically Current could also be `Current = 1 << 0` or `Current = 1 << None`, and as you said, `Past = 1 << Current`, `Future = 1 << Past` will work just as I had above.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ((flags & PAST) == PAST)
{
  // PAST is there
}

if ((flags & CURRENT) != CURRENT)
{
  // CURRENT is not there
}
```

Comment: A shame it is wrong (doesn't compile)... in C# you need brackets around the (flags & CURRENT)

Comment: @Marc Gravell, why would you post this comment and not edit the post for the guy?

Answer (score 0):

```
(value & Current) == Current
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what is missing is to take "all" but one

```
[Flags]
public enum Time
{
    None = 0,
    Current = 1,
    Past = 1 << 1, // 2, 10 binary
    Future = 1 << 2, // 4, 100 binary
    All = Current | Past | Future
}
```

Then with the above flags enum, you can do

```
var notNow= Time&~Time.Current;
```