# How does the tilde operator work in c#

Tags: c#, unmanaged

```
intStyle = intStyle & ~(WS_MINIMIZE);
```

It is the first time I see this , I am trying to learn how to hook low lvl APIs to C# and make some calls , and I do not understand what this line means. Thank you guys!

Comment: Please change the title of your question to make it more specific and helpful to future SO visitors. Something like "How does the tilde operator work in c#"

Comment: `0000100` apply operator `~0000100` will become `1111011`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an operation on a flag. You need to understand bitoperations (AND, OR, NOT, XOR..) for that. This line deletes the flag `WS_MINIMIZE` from the `intStyle` flagmask. More reading: [Using Bitwise operators on flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530077/using-bitwise-operators-on-flags) , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13740/The-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Using-Enum-Flags.

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) for the & operator.

And [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx) for the ~ operator

They are bitwise operators. The first one is a bitwise AND. The second one performs a bitwise complement operation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bitwise operation.

See for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V

Comment: Ohhh a bitwise operator! Ok! That makes sense. Thank you!